# How do I turn this into a loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I'm new to c++ and trying to convert the following statements into a loop of expressions being read from a file.  The following series of statements works fine when I supply input from the terminal:

```
int main()
{
    Expression* expression;
    char paren, comma;
    cout << "Enter expression: ";
    cin >> paren;
    expression = SubExpression::parse();
    cin >> comma;
    parseAssignments();
    cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But instead of passing in an expression from `cin`, which I must enter at a terminal, I'd like to read a file line by line and pass it into the program (which terminates at a newline character).

I've tried doing the following but the program gets locked at `cin`.  Any suggestions on how to modify my code to do this?

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt", ifstream::in);

    string line;
    while(inFile.good()) 
    {
       Expression* expression;
       char paren, comma;
       cin >> line;
       paren = line[0];
       expression = SubExpression::parse();
       cin >> line;
       comma = line.back();
       parseAssignments();
       cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate() << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to read from the file, so use `inFile` instead of `cin`.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt", ifstream::in);

    string line;
    while(inFile.good()) 
    {
       Expression* expression;
       char paren, comma;
       inFile >> line; // change this line
       paren = line[0];
       expression = SubExpression::parse();
       inFile >> line; // change this line
       comma = line.back();
       parseAssignments();
       cout << "Value = " << expression->evaluate() << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but what does the `>>` do when paired with `inFile`?  Is it pipe?

Comment: It is a [overloaded operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) to read and store data.

Comment: @free_mind: It does the same thing it does with `cin`, except it gets its characters from the file instead of the terminal.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley thanks to you both, that makes a lot of sense.  Since my `SubExpression::parse();` also needs to read from the same `inFile` stream, should I just pass the stream as a parameter to `SubExpression::parse();`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use oldschool C style

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
char buffer[5000];
while(fgets(buffer,5000,fp) != NULL){
//do something with line 'buffer'
}
fclose(fp);
```

Ps: sorry for short answer i am on mobile

ALSO depending on your OS, fgets may include the new line char in the buffer after it reads each line.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` reads from standard input which is usually the terminal. To read from the file, you'll need to use your `inFile` variable where you are using `cin`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a file named `input.txt`, try the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("input.txt",std::ifstream::in);
    std::string line;

    while(getline(fin, line))
    {
        std::cout<<line<<"\n";
    }

    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```